# Oracle Forms 10 auto save form data

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, autosave, form-data

He is there a function or setting which automaticly save's the form's data when a user forgot to press save? Like Word has?

Answer (score 2):

You need to code it yourself.

For example, you could add a `COMMIT_FORM` call to a form-level `KEY-EXIT` trigger. You might have to check what's in your `WHEN-WINDOW-CLOSED` trigger as well.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't.  You may be able to do something using TIMERs, but I wouldn't recommend it really.  Whereas Word is handling a single user's changes to a single document, Oracle is handling potentially many users' concurrent changes to many tables.  If your form auto-saves and the user didn't want those changes saved, you can't just "undo" the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Let try a jquery which is sisyphus jquery.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/05/sisyphus-js-client-side-drafts-and-more/

https://github.com/dnoonan/sisyphus-rails